# Несколько ключей для одного объекта

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, классы

Мне необходимо связать несколько ключей с одним объектом.
Например, у меня есть такой код:

```
var obj = {
  1 : "class1",
  2 : "class1",
  3 : "class2",
  4 : "class2",
  5 : "class3",
  6 : "class3",
  7 : "class4",
  ...
  n : "classn",
};
```

И мне необходимо не маленькому кол-ву див присвоить классы, согласно индексу. Делаю я это в jquery, вот так:

```
$('.container div').each(function(i) {
  $(this).addClass(obj[i]);
});
```

Все работает хорошо, но у меня таких див будет десятки.. И представьте для каждого дива писать его индекс и класс внутри `obj` это как-то немного не разумно.

В коде, что выше, каждому ключу присвоены объекты. А мне нужно наоборот.. Для одного объекта несколько ключей. Что-то вроде такого:

```
var obj = {
  1, 2 : "class1",
  3, 4 : "class2",
  5, 6 : "class3",
  7, 8, 9, 10 : "class4",
  ...
  n, n2 : "classn",
};
```

Но так не работает, и не будет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне сделать что ни будь подобное, что бы не плодить строчки для каждого ключа. Т.е. мне нужно одному объекту присвоить несколько ключей. Как это можно сделать? Спасибо! Мне это очень нужно..

Comment: не понятно зачем тебе в данном случае объект, какую функцию он выполняет? Вполне можно без него обойтись, скорее нужно, если конечно нет другого предназначения, о котором не подозреваю...

Comment: `$('.container div').each(function(i) {$(this).addClass("class" + [i]);});`

Comment: дак у меня классы то разные добавляются в дивы. Грубо говоря, с 1-го по 15 ключ - один класс, с 16 по 50 + 55 ключ и 57 - другой класс

Comment: тут ясновидящих нет.... Оформи вопрос так, чтобы не приходилось наводящие вопросы задавать.... людям гадать, что ты хочешь в конечном итоге получить???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете попробовать сделать наоборот:

```js
const obj = {
  "class1": [1, 2, 3, 4],
  "class2": [5, 6, 7],
  "class3": [8, 9, 10]
}

const objKeys = Object.keys(obj),
  objValues = Object.values(obj);

const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.container div');

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  let index = objValues.findIndex(ids => ids.indexOf(i + 1) > -1)

  if (index > -1) {
    nodes[i].classList.add(objKeys[index]);
  }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, попробую

Comment: работает изумительно. то, что и хотел. спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var obj0 = {
  class1: [1, 2],
  class2: [3, 4],
  class3: [5, 6],
  class4: [7, 8, 9, 10],
}

var obj = {}

for (var [c, a] of Object.entries(obj0)) {
  for (var i of a) {
    obj[i] = c
  }
}

console.log(obj)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: Хорошее решение. Спасибо)